# Volume of SKAudioNode

Tags: objective-c, audio, sprite-kit

I am using an SKAudioNode to play music for my game. I am wondering: what are the maximum and minimum values for the `volume`of the node? I am changing it using the SKAction: `[SKAction changeVolumeTo:0 duration:0];` Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you ctrl-click on the action on the code in Xcode it pops up with the details of the parameters

> class func changeVolume(to v: Float, duration: TimeInterval) ->
> SKAction
>
> Description - Creates an action that changes an audio node’s volume to
> a new value. When the action executes, the audio node’s volume
> animates from its current value to its new value. For more
> information, see AVAudio3DMixing.
>
> This action - v The new value for the volume. The value should be
> between 0.0 (silence) and 1.0 (maximum value for source audio),
> inclusive.
>
> duration - The duration of the animation, in seconds.
>
> Returns A new action object.
>
> SDKs  iOS 9.0+, macOS 10.11+, tvOS 9.0+, watchOS 2.0+

Comment: your welcome, hopefully the trick of how to get this info will help in the future as well